# NullPointerException when creating Fragment

Tags: android, button, android-fragments

I'm having an issue making a button work in a fragment, I've tried many things and trawled the forums but just cant get it working any help would be amazing!!!

Fragment class

```
    package info.androidhive.tabsswipe;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Spinner;

    public class BreakfastFragment extends Fragment {

     private Button button;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_breakfast, container, false);

        String[] tables = { "Where are you?", "Take out", "Table 1", "Table 2",
                "Table 3", "Table 4", "Table 5", "Table 6", };
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.table_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> tableadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                tables);

        String[] bagels = { "Pick your Bagel!", "Plain", "Wholemeal", "Seeded", };
        Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner_bageltype);
        ArrayAdapter<String> Bageladapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                bagels);

        String[] fillings = { "A tasty filling?", "Bacon", "Sausage",
                "Bacon & Sausage", "Soft Cheese", "Butter" };
        Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner_Filling);
        ArrayAdapter<String> fillingadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                fillings);

        String[] sauce = { "Any Sauce?", "Red", "Brown", "Mayo", "None", };
        Spinner spinner4 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner_sauce);
        ArrayAdapter<String> sauceadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sauce);

        tableadapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        Bageladapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        fillingadapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        sauceadapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        spinner.setAdapter(tableadapter);
        spinner2.setAdapter(Bageladapter);
        spinner3.setAdapter(fillingadapter);
        spinner4.setAdapter(sauceadapter);

         addListenerOnButton();

        return v;




    }   
    public void addListenerOnButton() {
             //Select a specific button to bundle it with the action you want
                button = (Button)  getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
                button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {

           }
                        });
    }
}
```

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff8400"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Breakfast Menu"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/table_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Enter your name" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Ready to order?"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_bageltype"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_Filling"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_sauce"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Set your Order!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

logcat

```
03-02 21:56:59.382: W/asset(32351): Copying FileAsset 0x69c2b938 (zip:/data/app/info.androidhive.tabsswipe-1.apk:/resources.arsc) to buffer size 4012 to make it aligned.
03-02 21:56:59.603: W/dalvikvm(32351): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41681970)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at info.androidhive.tabsswipe.BreakfastFragment.addListenerOnButton(BreakfastFragment.java:74)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at info.androidhive.tabsswipe.BreakfastFragment.onCreateView(BreakfastFragment.java:64)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16088)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5061)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16088)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5061)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16088)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5061)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2277)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16088)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2109)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1219)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1403)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5849)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:786)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:586)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:546)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:771)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
03-02 21:56:59.613: E/AndroidRuntime(32351):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 21:57:01.975: D/Process(32351): killProcess, pid=32351
03-02 21:57:01.975: D/Process(32351): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:123 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690
```

thanks guys its driving me crazy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into a **NullPointerException** at line 64 in your `BreakfastFragmentClass`.

```
at info.androidhive.tabsswipe.BreakfastFragment.onCreateView(BreakfastFragment.java:64)
```

This error occurs when you are **invoking a method on an object that is NULL** at that time.

The reason therefore could for example be that you are referencing an View id that is not in your layout file, or because you are calling `getActivity()` before the Fragments `onAttach(Activity a)` method is called.

In your case, the NullPointerException most likely occurs in this line:

```
 button = (Button)  getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Hand over the `View v;` from your `onCreaveView(...`) method instead of calling `getView()`. Like this:

```
public void addListenerOnButton(View v) {
           //Select a specific button to bundle it with the action you want
           button = (Button)  v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
           button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {

               }
         });
    }
```

Comment: Hi,  thanks for this, its stopped the error message when clicking (finally, couldn't see the wood for the trees!!!)  however I've added a simple toast into the code to test and nothing is happening any ideas 'Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Revewing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();'

Answer (score 0):

By default Spinner will selects the first item in its list.
so need to disable the first item in the spinner.